# catch StorageException when picture doesn`t exists on Firebase Store

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to check if the file exists or not on Firebase Store.

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReferenceenter storageRef = storage.getReference();
     try {
          storageRef.child(uID + ".jpg").getMetadata();
     } catch (Exception e) {
          
     }
```

but even if I use the try-catch it gives me :

```
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
    java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
```

I tried OnCompleteListener to check if its successful, but still gives this error.

Is there a way to check before the file exists or a way to catch this exception?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

getMetadata is asynchronous and always returns immediately.  You have to capture errors in the callback on the Task object it returns.  Use the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata#get_file_metadata) as your guide:

```
storageRef.getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {
        // Metadata now contains the metadata for 'images/forest.jpg'
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    }
});
```

You will not be able to use try/catch.  You must use the failure callback.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Doug Stevenson, I tried to  the Success and FailureListeners but still coming on the Run console the 
`E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}`.

Comment: Are you saying that the listeners don't get triggered at all on success or failure and the only thing you see is in the log?  You should add some logging or do step-through debugging to validate the behavior of the listeners.

Comment: They are getting triggered, and working as expected, only thing, it shows an error in the logs, and it doesnt look good. Thx in advance!

Comment: You can't control that.  If you want to file an issue for that behavior, then do that on GitHub (or build your own SDK from source): https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk